# DataGridViewAutoFilter и BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Вот так заполняю грид:

```
context.Invoces.Load();

var data = context.Shifts
    .Include(s => s.Routes)
    .Include(s => s.Tariff)
    .Include(s => s.Tariff.DeliveryTemperature)
    .Include(s => s.Tariff.TariffType)
    .Include(s => s.Tariff.TariffType.DeliveryType)
    .Include(s => s.TruckType)
    .Include(s => s.VisitedPoints)
    .Include(s => s.User)
    .Include(s => s.Depot)
    .Join(context.Invoces.Include(i => i.Shift), 
        s => s.Id,
        i => i.Shift.Id,
        (s,i) => new ShiftRow
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            ShiftCode = s.ShiftCode,
            CapacityKG = s.TruckType.MinimumKg + "-" + s.TruckType.MinimumKg,
            CapacityPal = s.TruckType.MinimumPal + "-" + s.TruckType.MaximumPal,
            TransportKG = s.Routes.Sum(r => r.KGsTransported),
            TransportPal = s.Routes.Sum(r => r.PalletsTransported),
            Created = s.DateCreated,
            DateDocument = s.DateDocument,
            Hours = i.Hours,
            Points = i.Points,
            Region = s.Depot.Region.Name,
            RegistrNumber = s.RegisterNumber,
            IsRef = s.Tariff.DeliveryTemperature.Value,
            KMs = i.KMs,
            ShiftName = s.Depot.Name + "-" + s.ShiftCode,
            Sum = i.Sum,
            Tariff = s.Tariff.Value,
            Trailer = s.TrailerNumber,
            TripNum = s.TripNumber,
            Truck = s.TruckNumber,
            TruckType = s.TruckType.MinimumKg + "/" + s.TruckType.MinimumKg,
            UserName = s.User.Login,

            p1 = s.VisitedPoints.Where(v => v.SerialNumber == 1).Select(v => v.Code).FirstOrDefault()
        }
    ).ToList();

_shiftRows = new BindingList<ShiftRow>(data);

_bindingSource = new BindingSource();
_bindingSource.DataSource = _shiftRows;            

dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;

// Add the AutoFilter header cell to each column.
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    col.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell);
}
```

После заполнения колонка не приобретает тип `DataGridViewAutoFilter` остается дефолтной. Почему?
С таким подходом работает:

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC tableRegistry @dateOne, @dateTwo, @shiftCode, @type";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateOne", SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateTwo", SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@shiftCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@dateOne"].Value = reportDateFrom;
cmd.Parameters["@dateTwo"].Value = reportDateTo;
cmd.Parameters["@shiftCode"].Value = shiftCode;
cmd.Parameters["@type"].Value = typeReportDate;
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
bs.DataSource = dt;
dgv_registry.DataSource = bs;
```

Я так понимаю причина в привязке? Надо костылить черед `DataTable`?

Comment: 'bs.DataSource = dt;' bs - это что?

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы работало, источник данных должен реализовывать `IBindingListView` интерфейс.
**EDIT:**
Не нашел ничего лучше кроме из List делать `DataTable`. Вот мой код:

```
private void GetDataOfRegistr(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    context.Invoces.Load();

    var data = context.Shifts
        .Include(s => s.Routes)
        .Include(s => s.Tariff)
        .Include(s => s.Tariff.DeliveryTemperature)
        .Include(s => s.Tariff.TariffType)
        .Include(s => s.Tariff.TariffType.DeliveryType)
        .Include(s => s.TruckType)
        .Include(s => s.VisitedPoints)
        .Include(s => s.User)
        .Include(s => s.Depot)
        .Join(context.Invoces.Include(i => i.Shift), 
            s => s.Id,
            i => i.Shift.Id,
            (s,i) => new ShiftRow
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                ShiftCode = s.ShiftCode,
                CapacityKG = s.TruckType.MinimumKg + "-" + s.TruckType.MinimumKg,
                CapacityPal = s.TruckType.MinimumPal + "-" + s.TruckType.MaximumPal,
                TransportKG = s.Routes.Sum(r => r.KGsTransported),
                TransportPal = s.Routes.Sum(r => r.PalletsTransported),
                Created = s.DateCreated,
                DateDocument = s.DateDocument,
                Hours = i.Hours,
                Points = i.Points,
                Region = s.Depot.Region.Name,
                RegistrNumber = s.RegisterNumber,
                IsRef = s.Tariff.DeliveryTemperature.Value,
                KMs = i.KMs,
                ShiftName = s.Depot.Name + "-" + s.ShiftCode,
                Sum = i.Sum,
                Tariff = s.Tariff.Value,
                Trailer = s.TrailerNumber,
                TripNum = s.TripNumber,
                Truck = s.TruckNumber,
                TruckType = s.TruckType.MinimumKg + "/" + s.TruckType.MinimumKg,
                UserName = s.User.Login,

                p1 = s.VisitedPoints.Where(v => v.SerialNumber == 1).Select(v => v.Code).FirstOrDefault()
            }
        ).ToList();

    DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(data);

    _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    _bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

    dgv_main.DataSource = _bindingSource;

    dgv_main.FilterStringChanged += Dgv_main_FilterStringChanged;
}

private void Dgv_main_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _bindingSource.Filter = dgv_main.FilterString;
}  

public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Для фильтрации вместо `datagridviewautofilter` использовал [adgv](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=adgv).